# Is it possible to have a function inside a completion handler?

Tags: swift

Is it possible to have a function inside a completion handler?
I want to save an image through a function after the user shared that same image in activity controller. 
I want to do the following:

```
let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [generateMemedImage()], applicationActivities: nil)
        self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        controller.completionWithItemsHandler = { 
            // Have this save() function when the activity has been completed
            func save() {
                //Save the meme
                let meme = Meme(topText: self.upperTextField.text!, lowerText: self.lowerTextField.text!, originalImage:
                    self.imageRetrieved.image!, memedImage: generateMemedImage())
            }
        }
```

Is there any better solution? Or how can I achieve this?

Comment: Why can't you make that save function on the same class as where you declare the controller and then have the completion handler capture it?  So call self.save() in the handler

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I got it saved using your suggestion. You are right, it was silly from me trying to have the function inside completition handler rather than calling it. Worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to declare a function inside the completion handler. Just write the code to perform the saving inside it, look

```
class Controller: UIViewController {

    func foo() {
        let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [generateMemedImage()], applicationActivities: nil)
        self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        controller.completionWithItemsHandler = { activityType, completed, returnedItems, error -> () in
            // write code to perform the save here <---
        }
    }

    func generateMemedImage() -> [AnyObject] {
        return []
    }

}
```

Comment: Just did, but it doesn't run it. I used breakpoint and it skips the code to perform the save

Comment: Please replace my placeholder (I mean this line `// write code to perform the save here`) with this `print("Completed!")` and let me know if you see the message into the console. Also please keep in mind that this code is executed when the `UIActivityViewController` is dismissed.

Comment: My bad, it did print. Worked perfectly with my code! I stopped and didn't wait for view being dismissed. Thanks